# Install a fileset if a system property is set

Tags: install4j

I have defined a fileset id='A' and want to install it only if a system property INSTALL_A=true is set.

I have created a Run script action before 'Install files' and added the following:

```
if ("true".equals(System.getProperty("INSTALL_A", "false"))) {
  context.getFileSetById("A").setSelected(true);
} else {
  context.getFileSetById("A").setSelected(false);
}
return true;
```

But the fileset always gets installed even if the system property is not set.

Any ideas welcome to debug the issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Had a similar issue: needed to use getFileSetByName rather than getFileSetById

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more concise way to write this would be

```
context.getFileSetById("A").setSelected(Boolean.getBoolean("INSTALL_A"));
return true;
```

This is the correct approach to conditionally install a file set. Either the system property or the file set do not exist. Try to add the following logging statements

```
Util.logInfo(null, "Install_A:" + Boolean.getBoolean("INSTALL_A"));
Util.logInfo(null, "File set A found " + (context.getFileSetById("A") != null));
```

to the beginning of the "Run script" action and check the log file .install4j\installation.log for the related output.